# Django Quiz- User Generated

Tags: python, django

So I have these models `Question`, `Answer`, and `UserAnswer` that make up a quiz. The problem I'm facing is making a form that validates with these models. I have an idea of how to do it but it's not working.

```
class QAForm(forms.Form):
    answers = forms.ChoiceField(label='Question is this', choices=[('Answer1','Answer1'),('Answer2','Answer2')], widget=forms.RadioSelect())
```

This works for 1 form, not for thousands. How would I modify this code so that users sees all of the user-generated questions & answers as form and can provide their own answer to it.

I have this (it works but I know it's not a good practice):

```
def questions(request):
    queryset = Questions.objects.all()
    if request.method =='POST':
        a = request.POST['answer']
        answer = Answer.objects.get(answer=a)
        importance = request.POST['importance']
        q = request.POST['question']
        question = Questions.objects.get(id=q)
        try:
            user_answer = UserAnswers.objects.get(owner=request.user, question=question)
            user_answer.answer = answer
            user_answer.importance = importance
            user_answer.save()
        except:
            user_answer = UserAnswers(owner=request.user, question=question, answer=answer, importance=importance)
            user_answer.save()
    else:
        try:
            current = UserAnswers.objects.all().filter(owner=request.user)
        except:
            current = ''
return render_to_response("questions/base.html", locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

My models:

```
class Answer(models.Model):
        answer = models.CharField(max_length=120)
        question = models.ForeignKey('Questions', null=True, blank=True)

        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.answer

IMPORTANCE = (
        ('Irrelevant', 'Irrelevant'),
        ('A Little Important', 'A Little Important'),
        ('Somewhat Important', 'Somewhat Important'),
        ('Very Important', 'Very Important'),
        ('Mandatory', 'Mandatory'),
)

class Questions(models.Model):
        owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
        question = models.CharField(max_length=300)
        importance = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=IMPORTANCE, null=True, blank=True)
        updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
        timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.question

        class Meta:
                verbose_name            ='Question'
                verbose_name_plural     ='Questions'


class UserAnswers(models.Model):
        owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
        question = models.ForeignKey(Questions)
        answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer)
        importance = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=IMPORTANCE)

        def __unicode__(self):
                return str(self.owner) + " " + str(self.answer) + " " + str(self.importance)
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @arulmr just added my views to show you how I currently have it working.

Comment: the user generated part works fine. It's the rendering of the forms that doesn't work correctly.

Comment: You're not validating the form at all. See this example https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view. If you need thousands of same form, check Formset out. If you want to build forms from models, check ModelForm out.

Comment: @Bibhas yeah I realize the form is not validating. How would you implement a question and answer form? Such that there are both separate models?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this? (Haven't actually tested it, but it should work)

```
class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    answer = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, widget=forms.RadioSelect())

    def __init__(self, question=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QuestionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['answer'].choices = [(a.text, a.value) for a in Answer.objects.filter(question=question)]

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('text')
```

Then initiating it like -

```
q = Question.objects.get(pk=1)
qform = QuestionForm(instance=q)
```

This can be done when you want just one form. You can use a [FormSet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/) if you want thousands of it.

PS: I'm assuming the Answer model has a foreignkey to the Question model and they have already been filled up.

Comment: Dude! that works pretty well. Thanks a lot. The problem I have now, is it shows all objects from the Answer model (instead of associated ones.) I'll update my original question to include my models.

Comment: TBH: You don't need the manytomany relationship to Answer. Answers are already related to Questions with Foreignkey in many-to-one relationship. Remove the line `answers = models.ManyToManyField(Answer)` And check for the values of the foreignkey field of the answers.

Comment: oh yeah thank you. I have been playing around with this for a while to get desired results. It works well now except calling `form.cleaned_data['answer']` returns all answer instances instead of the selected one. (same happens with `request.POST['answer']`)

Comment: You had a messed up relationship. Clean that up.

Answer (score 2):

Latest code for your demand. You can try this code :

```
class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    answer = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, widget=forms.RadioSelect())

def __init__(self, question=None, *args, **kwargs):
    super(QuestionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['answer'].choices = [(a.text, a.value) for a in Answer.objects.filter(question=question)]

class Meta:
    model = Question
    fields = ('text')
```

[general knowledge](http://www.knowledgefair.net)